# Chef stand alone notify

Tags: chef-infra

Using Chef, I'd like to use the notification functionality outside the context of calling another resource.

Here's what I've been doing as a work around, but I want to know if there is a cleaner way to do this:

```
execute 'restart myapp' do
  command '/srv/www/myapp/shared/scripts/myapp restart'
  action :nothing
end

# Code here does configuration and dependencies restart notifications

execute 'echo "Restarting myapp"' do
  notifies :run, 'execute[restart myapp]'
end
```

The key here is that I need `execute[restart myapp]` to run after all the other potential notifications from earlier in the recipe.

Comment: basically that's fine - except that you could send an `action :delete` to a `file` resource.

Comment: It's just a basic example. I'm not actually deleting a single file in practice.

Comment: fine. then keep it like it is - or provide more details of the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save a milliseconds by making that

```
ruby_block 'noop' do
  block { }
  notifies :run, 'execute[cleanup]'
end
```

But in general be wary of this kind of design. Delayed notifications are a one-trick pony, there is no way to get a "later than all deferreds" for example. Consider using a custom resource and more tightly scoping the behaviors you need to a single action method.

Comment: So basically you are saying to rewrite the resource so that it doesn't use notifications and instead just executes each command inline when it's time for it to execute?

Comment: Yes, with each execute being internally idempotent.